# How to use Truffle with Solidity 6.0?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

Reading official Truffle docs, I noticed Truffle not support Solidity 6.0

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;
```

Are there any ways to use Truffle with Solidity 6.0?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wA2ltwauvRw - follow this link. This link will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this works with this migration

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }
}
```

And this compiler settings

```
compilers: {
     solc: {
       version: "^0.6.0",
```

And also need re-install Truffle to latest version

Answer (score 0):

You can set the solidity version in the **truffle config** file.

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1", // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 7545, // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*", // Any network (default: none)
    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.6.0",
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true, // Default: false
          runs: 1000, // Default: 200
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```